# A question about defective DVD players and conditional probabaility.

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A quality control inspector DVD players for a complete inspection as they come off the assembly line.

It is known that 10% of all the items are defective.

Also, 60% of all defective items and 20% of all good items undergo a complete inspection.

a) if a randomly selected DVD player undergoes a complete inspection,what is the probability it is defective?

b)if a certain dvd pLayer did not undergo a complete inspection,what is the probability it is not defective?

It’s been a while since I have problems like these. Any nudging towards the process would be appreciated!

My work:

a) since 10% of the items are known to be defective and 60% of defective items undergo a complete inspection, the probability of a randomly selected DVD player to be inspected that is defective is
1/10*6/10 = 6%

[image: these are the percentages of what I found]

Answer (score 1):

> the probability of a randomly selected DVD player to be inspected that is defective is 1/10*6/10 = 6%

In your attempt, you've ignored the fact that even *good items can be inspected*. In fact, by this calculation, you're answering the question "what is the probability of that a disc selected out of *the complete sample space* underwent inspection *and* was defective?" However, in the given question, the sample space is restricted to *only* those items which underwent inspection.

---

> Any nudging towards the process would be appreciated!

Sure, here you go:

For part (a):

Let $x$ be the total number of the items. Then, you should note that $0.1x$ are defective items (given: "It is known that 10% of all the items are defective."). So, $0.6\cdot0.1x=0.06x$ items undergo complete inspection *and* are defective, while $0.2\cdot0.9x=0.18x$ items undergo complete inspection *and* are good. Can you solve part (a) now?

Solution below:

> Probability = $\frac{\text{favorable outcome}}{\text{total outcomes}}=\frac{0.06x}{0.06x+0.18x}=0.25$

---

The other part (b) is similar to part(a), and understanding (a) you should be able to solve (b).

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:** Solution for part (b)

> $0.4\cdot0.1x=0.04$ defective items did not undergo inspection. $0.8\cdot0.9x=0.72x$ good items did not undergo inspection. So, probability = $$\frac{\text{favourable outcomes}}{\text{total outcomes}}=\frac{0.72x}{0.76x}=\frac{18}{19}$$

Comment: I believe I got 94% for part B , is that remotely correct?

Comment: @user338365 In case you approximated your answer, it is correct. Do tally your solution with mine (updated for part b)